# Laravel: Installing Passport in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-passport

I have successfully installed the Laravel with **Passport** utility in my sub folder on the server. Everything is working perfectly except the fact that I am unable to create Personal access token. On investigating, I  found that it was due to the fact the path was not forming incorrectly.

path forming -> **site/oauth/personal-access-token** 
URL should be -> **site/subfolder/oauth/personal-access-toke**n

I manually tried to change the path in **authorize.php, app.js** and all the **.vue files**, but it didn't work. It caused the path to include the sub-folder twice in the path.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved. I have to add

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://example.com/your-subfolder';

in bootsratp.js file